# How to get data which is not empty in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.6.7. I have table named 'customers' where email is 'none' as default in table structure. I repeat it is not NULL as default. So when email field is empty then this field is not set as null. In this case how can I retrieve all data which is not empty. I tried this:

```
$customers =  $this->Customer->find('list', 
                 array('fields' => array('email'),
                 'conditions' => array('event_id' => $this->request->data['Product']['event_id'],
                      'not' => array('Customer.email' => null) 
                  )
              )
          );
```

`print_r($customers);` gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [103] => shuvo2782@gmail.com
    [104] => tanjimtasfia95@gmail.com
    [105] => tsiddique10@gmail.com
    [106] => mahrana78@gmail.com
    [107] => snehomay@yahoo.com
    [108] => raifurrhaim95@gmail.com
    [109] => billahm9@gmail.com
    [110] => rahamanraju27@gmail.com
    [111] => shaiful019@gmail.com
    [112] => tawhid.cse@gmail.com
    [113] => minhaazulislaam@gmail.com
    [114] => helalkhan32@gmail.com
    [115] => mshuvo080@gmail.com
    [116] => jahidiu@gmail.com
    [117] => rezahimel@gmail.com
    [118] => soniagazi123@yahoo.com
    [119] => MDRAFIQUEL.ISLAM457@GMAIL.COM
    [120] => khan7733305@gmail.com
    [121] => khrimel@yahoo.com
    [122] => Kawserrabbi3@gmail.com
    [123] => mr.samirulhaque@gmail.com
    [124] => tithydac@yahoo.com
    [125] => iftefci@yahoo.com
    [126] => nipabangla@gmail.com
    [127] => asheke.elahi15@gmail.com
    [128] => enam_moni@yahoo.com
    [129] => tipshridoy@gmail.com
    [130] => easirarafat95@yahoo.com
    [131] => munem.sohan@yahoo.com
    [132] => mdmamunkobi9@gmail.com
    [133] => zarinnpn@gmail.com
    [134] => antohin.munna@gmail.com
    [135] => isratpriyanka36@gmail.com
    [136] => lipa.bhuiyan@yahoo.com
    [137] => ra.latifa94@gmail.com
    [138] => rif007at@gmail.com
    [139] => jayadnur@gmail.com
    [140] => gopalthmdu09@gmail.com
    [141] => mehedidon007@gmail.com
    [142] => ahmd.shuhan@gmail.com
    [143] => md.jami.94@gmail.com
    [144] => prokash811@gmail.com
    [145] => yiran786@gmail.com
    [146] => akashecejkkniu@gmail.com
    [147] => aktermowsumi@gmail.com
    [148] => rhythm55@live.com
    [149] => msisohan@yahoo.com
    [150] => lizan1915@yahoo.com
    [151] => mfrjnp@gmail.com
    [152] => mithun.r0503@gmail.com
    [153] => estiaqhasanthe@gmail.com
    [154] => Mohinuddin817@gmail.com 
    [155] => meghlashokal25@gmail.com
    [156] => mithun.r0503@hotmail.com
    [157] => Sudipto004.ruet@gmail.Com
    [158] => tetys.sourov@gmail.com
    [159] => arefindipu464@gmail.com
    [160] => zahirulislam425@gmail.com
    [161] => ibrahimshaikhibu@gmail.com
    [162] => www.zeromsi2@gmail.com
    [163] => sabuj26@gmail.com
    [164] => prince.munem.maruf@gmail.com
    [165] => crossbonesdipu@gmail.com
    [166] => iconfaysal2013@gmail.com
    [167] => mosharof34@diit.info
    [168] => drnira007@ymail.com
    [169] => yeasinmina90@gmail.com
    [170] => masudurism@gmail.com
    [171] => shafiqklislamdch@gmail.com
    [172] => wdxshohag@gmail.com
    [173] => mostafij.hemal@gmail.com
    [174] => miron.miron15@gmail.com
    [175] => tanvir.hossain53@gmail.com
    [176] => razuahammad@outlook.com
    [177] => mohsin.akanda@gmail.com
    [178] => iraz12729@gmail.com
    [179] => mostainbillah96@gmail.com
    [180] => munnarahman1994@gmail.com
    [181] => olosut@yahoo.com
    [182] => tope_olosu@yahoo.com
    [183] => hamimulislam@gmail.com
    [184] => Lipikhatun446@gmail.com
    [185] => cse0607007@gmail.com
    [186] => saim.shohag@gmail.com
    [187] => rubiatrafi@gmail.com
    [188] => jonalex628@gmail.com
    [189] => mirashikul.haque14@gmail.com
    [190] => rizvyr@gmail.com
    [191] => mafuz619 Gmail . com
    [192] => jahedul005@gmail.com
    [193] => masuq2014@gmail.com
    [194] => amrobi15@yahoo.com
    [195] => asma@systechunimax.com
    [196] => farzanaislam12@gmail.com
    [197] => 
    [198] => 
    [199] => 
    [200] => 
    [201] => 
    [202] => 
    [203] => 
    [204] => 
    [205] => 
    [206] => 
    [207] => 
    [208] => 
    [209] => 
    [210] => 
    [211] => 
    [212] => 
    [213] => 
    [214] => 
    [215] => 
    [216] => 
    [217] => 
    [218] => 
    [219] => 
    [220] => 
)
```

It logical that the email field is not null when no value for email is provided but I am trying to filtering this empty value telling as NOT NULL. Is there any way to solve this issues ?

Comment: Pass an empty string to the not value i.e. `'not' => array('Customer.email' => '')`

Comment: Great! It works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please add condition like

```
$customers =  $this->Customer->find('list', 
                 array('fields' => array('email'),
                 'conditions' => array('event_id' => $this->request->data['Product']['event_id'],
                      'AND' => array('not' => array('Customer.email' => null),'not' => array('Customer.email' => '') 
                  )
              )
          );
```